# Unable to Get the hidden field value in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When I am executing the below mentioned code on asp.net web form I am getting the value of hidden field customerDeviceIdReferenceCode on page source.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" id="customerDeviceIdReferenceCode" name="customerDeviceIdReferenceCode" value=""/>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<#-- populate customer device id -->
        var io_bbout_element_id = 'customerDeviceIdReferenceCode'; 
        //<#-- do not install Flash        -->
        var io_install_flash = false;  
        //<#-- do not install Active X     -->
        var io_install_stm = false; 
        //<#-- do not run Active X         -->
        var io_exclude_stm = 12;   
        //<#-- enable detection of real IP -->
        var io_enable_rip = true;                               

        (function () {
            var asyncSnareScript = function() {
                var element = document.createElement('script');
                element.src = "https://ci-mpsnare.iovation.com/snare.js";
                document.body.appendChild(element);    

            };

            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener('load', asyncSnareScript, false);
            } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                window.attachEvent('onload', asyncSnareScript);
            } else {
                //<#-- If all else fails, just append the script immediately. -->
                asyncSnareScript();
            }
            //alert('2');

        })();


</script>
```

I want to move the same code to an MVC application.After moving the code to MVC , I have removed form tag in View.But now I am not getting the value of hidden field customerDeviceIdReferenceCode on page source.
Please suggest how should I proceed in MVC.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is page source? Are you posting this back to a controller action? Show your model and code on the MVC side.

Comment: @SteveGreene : I have not defined any model as of now.I just have to include this thing in my view.I have created a Controller/View and written that piece of code. I am unsure of how to proceed .

Comment: where are you actually setting the value?

Comment: @JamieD77 . I have to set the value.In asp.net when I executed the aforementioned snippet I got the value in hidden field.Now I have to move the code from asp.net to mvc. I am not able to do it despite trying different combinations.

Comment: where have you written the code to access hidden field's value ?

Answer (score 0):

in MVC `customerDeviceIdReferenceCode` will likely be a property on your model.
So use razor `@html.HiddenFor(x => x.customerDeviceIdReferenceCode)`